# How come an older question can be marked a duplicate of a newer question?

Tags: discussion

[June 20 question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224447/do-i-need-a-dweller-in-the-storage-room)

[June 23 question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224914/should-i-assign-dwellers-to-the-storage-room)

The core of the questions are practically the same, but how come the older question for June 20 is marked a duplicate of a newer question posted on June 23?

Comment: Age tends to be of lesser importance than answer quality.